# Alternative to Chrome Extension "Window Resizer"

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, resize, responsive-design

In light of the [recent controversy (Dec 2013)](http://www.reddit.com/r/YouShouldKnow/comments/1snyyl/ysk_the_chrome_extension_called_window_resizer/) over the Chrome extension titled "Window Resizer", what are some alternative solutions to quickly resizing the Chrome browser for responsive development testing?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Resolution Test could be a possible alternative.

> Resolution Test changes the size of the browser window for developers
>   to preview their websites in different screen resolutions. It includes
>   a list of commonly used resolutions and the ability to customise that
>   list. It also gives users the option to turn on Google Browser Size.

It is available in the Chrome webstore:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/resolution-test/idhfcdbheobinplaamokffboaccidbal

Comment: awesome - don't know how I missed it!  Thanks

Answer (score 34):

Another native solution to test responsive designs is to use the built-in Chrome Developer Tools.  Choose Tools->Developer Tools, then click the gear icon in the bottom-right corner of the window that pops up.  Click "Enable" then click "Device Metrics" and you can specify whatever resolution you'd like to replicate.

Also, by changing the "User Agent" on that screen, Chrome sets the device metrics for the chosen device, which may come in-handy when deciding where your responsive breakpoints should be for the more-popular devices.

This isn't as easy as a two-click extension, but it has the advantage of being an extension-less solution, and also using exact screen measurements of actual devices.

Comment: This is a **GREAT suggestion**, but I needed better directions... here is [Google's link to do this](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/mobile-emulation)

Answer (score 21):

**YES!**

I recommend avoiding extensions, master chrome dev tools with [keyboard shortcuts](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/shortcuts).

Open them using
<kbd>F12</kbd>
or
<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>(Gnu/Linux or Windows)
<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>opt</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>(Mac)
or
Menu > Tools > Developer Tools

EDIT: Screenshots updated to reflect chrome dev tools recent changes.

[image: screenshot - step 1 of 2]
[image: screenshot - step 2 of 2]

A gif says it better!

[image: gif screencast with all steps]
(hint: open image in new tab)

Comment: For us Mac-folks using Chrome, what are the instructions there?

Comment: I just added mac option and a link to the official documentation.

Comment: Have you actually tried that on a Mac? I get to an almost empty small page which allows me to view a "drawer", but that doesn't have "Devices".

Comment: I think I might have skipped 1 step, you need to select the "Emulation" tab in the drawer. It would normally open the "Console" by default.

Comment: After getting to Emulation, there's no Screen option. Maybe because I'm on a laptop computer, not a mobile device. What I see doesn't come close to what you showed.

Comment: Turns out things have changed since I last used that feature. Now you have to click on the little mobile/cellphone icon. There are instructions right there in the emulation tab. But a gif always says it better. There you go, hope it was helpful ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, "Open Image in a New Tab" causes Chrome to "freeze" for a lengthy period of time. The small gif on this page works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a window resizer bookmarklet that works great:

http://lab.maltewassermann.com/viewport-resizer/

Answer (score 3):

To update @Dave's answer, as of Chrome 35.0.1916.153 m, you need to select the Show drawer icon (>=) to the left of the gear icon, select Sources then the Emulation tab.

To get the most current tools go to @FireCodings [link](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/mobile-emulation) to Google's mobile emulation development tools, and download/install [Chrome Canary](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/canary.html). Then in Canary choose Tools->Developer Tools, click the mobile icon in the top-left corner of the tools window (at the bottom of the browser), click Sources, and then Emulation. The information is there on the Google page link to demonstrate how to use the tools.

Answer (score 2):

Another (safer) alternative is to make you own.

Google has a lot of [documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html) on creating extensions. I made this [really simple extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/browser-resize/pnmdcoaajafdppfpioijldebfbpogopn) which does all I needed for a project, you can also find the code for this on [github](https://github.com/grahamlicence/chrome-resize).

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the developer backed down and ended up removing the offending piece of code (called "Ecolinks") from their extension. As of today, the affiliate stuff is supposed to be gone.

Source: https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/mlAD1ygc0v0/gKLKWxoGrkIJ

Changelog for version 1.9.0.3

> Version 1.9.0.3 (2014-01-15): Due to popular demand, I have removed
>   the EcoLinks.

Comment: I'm sorry but the trust has already been violated. The stated purpose of the product had nothing to do with proxying users' traffic or redirecting anything, yet that's what was happening.  If you want to give it a second chance be my guest, but I cannot afford the risk.  But thanks for the update - some will appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

On **Windows** with **AutoHotKey** installed, save the below in resize-chrome.ahk and double-click to run:

```
WinMove, ahk_exe chrome.exe,, 0, 0, 1024, 768
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this once. I find it better than any other Chrome extension.

[link](http://lab.maltewassermann.com/viewport-resizer/)

Answer (score -5):

You can download the extension directly from this post in the official developer site

http://windowresizer.userecho.com/topic/353032-did-you-pull-your-extension-from-the-google-store/

I was trying find something to use too, but none is like this extension, the best to me so far

Comment: That extension installs functionality that hijacks your google search results and adds amazon affiliate links to your amazon searches. There's a reason it was removed from the Google App store.

Comment: Yes, and that reason is it did not comply with this:
_"Ads must be presented in context with your app or **clearly state which app they are bundled with**. Ads must also be easily removable by either adjusting the settings or uninstalling the app(s) altogether. Ads may not simulate or impersonate system notifications or warnings."_