# Media query not working for desktop

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do a CSS for just my desktop, therefore i used the media query like below to link my css with my desktop.

My desktop resolution is 1440 x 900. Hence, my media query css for desktop is like this below

```
@media (max-width: 1440px) {

  #loginpage {
    position:relative;
    margin-top:15%;
  }

  #headerbodyadmin {
    position:relative;
    margin-top:20%;
  }

}
```

I tried used this method as well.

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 1440px){
}
```

Unfortunately, it's not working. I checked the various media query tutorial and this seems to be the correct way to implement css for my desktop resolution 1440x900.

May i know did i do anything wrong here?

Comment: Shouldn't you just make queries for mobile and tablet and then the default would be desktop? Desktop's dont really need a query.

Comment: What do you mean its not working? [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/J5jMW/)

Comment: @Ruddy because i used the above CSS code above in my webapp in VS2012 but there isn't any changes in the positioning of my elements. Not very sure why are you guys able to work it out :/

Comment: Is your browser window really 1400px wide? Maybe the width of the scrollbar gets substracted?!

Comment: I used this website to check the resolution of my computer [here is the link](http://www.whatismyscreenresolution.com/)

Comment: The website shows the screen resolution and not the browser width (at least in my case). If you are using Chrome you can add a extension: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20775775/alternative-to-chrome-extension-window-resizer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding one pixel to your max-width , `@media (max-width: 1441px)`

Answer (score 1):

I checked the code and it working fine, make sure that you referenced id's in html page also.

Check this URL : http://jsfiddle.net/Ravichand/8kznk/

```
@media  (max-width: 1440px) {

#loginpage {
position:relative;
margin-top:15%;
color:red;
}

#headerbodyadmin {
position:relative;
margin-top:20%;
color:skyblue;
}
}
```

Comment: its so strange, that my mobile query   @media only screen
  and (max-device-width: 700px) only worked for mobile phones but i wanted it also to work for people who like to shrink their tabs to take up half the screen too and your max-width works for phones and desktops

Answer (score 0):

I checked that and it works, here you can find example

http://jsfiddle.net/7VVsA/

```
@media (max-width: 1440px) {

  #loginpage {
    position:relative;
    margin-top:15%;
    background:red;
  }

  #headerbodyadmin {
    position:relative;
    margin-top:20%;
    background:yellow;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries#width) and [`height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries#height) attribute describes the length for the view port and not the device screen resolution as [`device-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries#device-width) and [`device-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries#device-height). If you use the `width` attribute it is possible that the considered value is smaller then your screen resolution width, because there is a border around the window or a scroll bar. Browsers on mobile devices usually utilize the entire width of the screen, so you don't see this effect there. Here what MDN says to the `width` attribute:

> The width media feature describes the width of the rendering surface of the output device (such as the width of the document window, or the width of the page box on a printer).

So if you want to trigger the styles if your device has a width resolution of `1440px` I would use it like this:

```
@media (max-device-width: 1440px) {
    /* your style */
}
```

You can read [more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) about this in the MDN documentation. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747242/what-is-the-difference-between-max-device-width-and-max-width-for-mobile-web) question is also interesting.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 01:** Instead of `max width`. you can use `min-width`

Like

```
/*Sizes above 1024*/
@media (min-width: 1024px) {

}
```

**Solution 02:** Or you can try adding `+1` to your width

Like

```
/*width 1441 to avoid any other conflict */
@media (max-width: 1441px) {

}
```